# find the connected covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \lor \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

This is a problem on Hatcher' book. How to find all the connected  covering spaces of  $\mathbb{R}P^2 \lor \mathbb{R}P^2$? I don't know where to start. Is there a general way to construct the connected covering space of a giving space?

Comment: Have you figured out what the universal cover is yet? That's the first step in my opinion.

Comment: Have you calculated the fundamental group?

Comment: the fundamental group is $<a,b|a^2=1,b^2=1>$.I don't understand what you mean. Could you give the details? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now that you know the fundamental group, you can find the covering spaces by finding conjugacy classes of subgroups and considering quotients of the universal cover of those subgroups.

Comment: I'm sorry. I know a little on free group. How to find the subgroups  of this fundamental group? Actually, we need find all conjugacy classes of subgroups. How to find them? I know that $Z_2$ and $Z$ must be its subgroup. After finding these subgroups, how to use the universal cover to construct the corresponding covering spaces of conjugacy classes of subgroups? Hatcher gives a theoretic proof, but I don't know the method in concrete example. I really want to understand this method.

Comment: You want to use geometric intuition to help you find the subgroups. Try to draw a few possible covering spaces and figure out which subgroups give rise to those.